# Unpacking Values from one input for integer handling?

Tags: python, error-handling, integer

First. I know this looks messy right now but there was a huge issue converting a py2.7 to py 3.5 code and i haven't cleaned it up. Moving on. I am trying to get the values to all unpack as one line. This code works but not as well as I would like. I can put in values for any other number from 1-9 and this will work but what if for example, i want to roll 1d20? or 10d4? I cannot seem to get the integers to separate. In both py2.7 and the py 3.5 as i have a working code for this now on both, if I (.split()) or (.join(" ")) the variables I still cannot get it to pull in the integers together as separate entries from the 'r3d4' line. as soon as i put in a double digit number, it stalls with an error 'Too Many Values to Unpack' or i get the 'int base 10' error. any ideas? I dont want to have to separate this into 'how many dice do you want to roll?' etc. i want a clean one line entry. The following code works here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter  but I am not sure if its 2.7 or 3.5

```
import random
print("Dice Roller testing")
roll, amount, dice, sides = str(input("Input the format. example: r3d4. rolls 3d4 "))
amount = int(amount)
sides = int(sides)
i = 1 
while i <= amount and roll == "r" and sides == 4: 
    x = random.randint(1, 4) 
    print(x)
    i = (i+1) 
while i <= amount and roll == "r" and sides == 6: 
    x = random.randint(1, 6) 
    print(x)
    i = (i+1) 
while i <= amount and roll == "r" and sides == 8: 
    x = random.randint(1, 8) 
    print(x)
    i = (i+1) 
else: 
    print("We are finished or the input is not valid.")
```

NVM. Got it.

Got it. Here is my code. (python 3.6.4)

```
import random
while True:
    user_input = str(input('test:  '))
    i = 1
    roll, sides = user_input.split("d")
    sides = int(sides)
    x, amount = roll.split("r")
    amount = int(amount)
    while i <= amount:
        n = random.randint(1,sides)
        print(n)
        i = i+1
```

Comment: Also, before you even say it. I do NOT want to deal with functions for this code. No function answers please.

Comment: you can't unpack that way. unpacking would have been possible if only the sides were > 10.

Comment: this isnt what i mean. I am able to unpack the above with 'r3d4' as an example. if you put in the print statements there or try it, it does unpack those. what i want to know is how to iterate or parse the entire tuple as letters and numbers separately, not every single input character as one item.

Answer (score 0):

with roll as your input

```
import re
exp = re.compile('r?(\d{1,2})d(\d{1,2})')
try:
    amount, faces = exp.fullmatch(roll).group(1,2)
except AttributeError:
    print('bad format')
```

if you use 100 faces or amounts change `\d{1,2}` according to the number of digits (ie: `\d{1,3}`)

Comment: i put my solve as an edit above. your code though pretty much loses readability...

Comment: @fantascey you can answer your own question and chose it as your selected answer

Comment: I cannot actually. before i learned how to just leave a comment i was using answers to ask questions, so my account is banned from answering. :(